# Dart: How to update value in Set

Tags: dart

How do I update the value at index `0`

```
Set<int> set = {1, 2, 3};
set[0] = 0; // error
```

**Note:**

I am not looking for workaround like convert `Set` to `List`, add element and further convert it back to `Set`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sets elements only have indices incidentally because they are iterables. You can't "update the value at position x" because any update may change the order.

I assume you do want to keep the iteration order (and in that case, you really should be using a list!), so the following won't work:

```
 void update<T>(Set<T> elements, int index, T newValue) {
   set.remove(set.elementAt(index));
   set.add(newValue);
 }
```

The problem here is that you won't preserve iteration order, the new value that you added is likely at the end of the iteration (if you are using an insertion-ordered set), or maybe the order has changed completely (if you are not).

An approach which works for insertion-ordered sets:

```
void replace<T>(Set<T> set, int index, T newValue) {
  if (set.contains(newValue)) throw StateError("New value already in set");
  int counter = 0;
  while (counter < set.length) {
    var element = set.first;
    set.remove(element);
    if (counter == index) element = newValue;
    set.add(element);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

This repeatedly removes the first element in the set, then inserts it again, except for the `index`th element, where it inserts `newValue` instead.
This *only* works for insertion-ordered sets (like the default `LinkedHashSet`).
(Notice that this will not work if `newValue` is already in the set, so I made it throw in that case).

For all other sets, there is no better solution that `(set.toList()..[index] = newValue).toSet()`.

Comment: You are so great dude, the understanding you have is just outstanding, thanks a bunch. Would be nice if you can share your secret of Dart!

Comment: Sir there is one error, `set.remove` doesn't return you deleted element it returns `bool` which tells you whether the element you are trying to delete was in set or not. So can you please update your `replace` method?

Comment: Good catch. Updating.

Comment: What about if we dont have that freedom e.g google maps flutter require polylines and marker in sets rather than list

Comment: `counter` does not seem to be updated in the while loop...

Comment: `counter` does not seem to be updated in the while loop...

Comment: `counter` does not seem to be updated in the while loop...

Answer (score 9):

You can not change values in a set directly with index, but you can do it with `map`.

```
Set<int> set = {1, 2, 3};
Set<int> updated = set.map((item) => item == 1 ? 0 : item).toSet();

print(updated); // => {0, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work that way but I need to do it using `index`, not the actual element. I upvoted your post though!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value in a set but you could get a similar result by converting it to a list and changing it back to set.

```
Set<int> set = {1,2,3};
List<int> list = set.toList();
list[1] = 12;
var newset = list.toSet();
```

this may be a quick solution to your problem.